# Adding character values to a generic type

Tags: ada

What generic type should i use, if I have to assign a Character value to it?
For now I'm using type `Char is(<>);` at the generic declaration,
and assign the character value like this:

```
XY:GenericChar;
CharacterVariable: Character:='A';

XY:=GenericChar'Value(Character'Image(CharacterVariable));
```

It works, but i think there should be a better way.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have a generic formal type which shares the properties of `Character` to the extent that they have the same literals. In which case, I have to ask 'why'? Please give some more context for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `'Pos` and `'Val`.

Converting between non-related enumeration types is non-trivial. Best would be to use a conversion function like:

```
generic
   type Generic_Char is (<>);
   with function To_Generic_Char (Source : Character) return Generic_Char is <>;
package Foo is
...
```

That way your generic package wouldn't have to care about converting.

For instantiating the package you would have to create the function.

Answer (score 1):

That generic formal parameter you are using can be supplied with any "discrete type". That means that the client can use any kind of integer-related type, or an enumeration, to instantiate your generic. It also means that only operations available to both integers and enumerations are available inside the routine.

For the most part that means you can assign `Char`s, you can compare them, and you have access to any attribute available to "discretes". Checking our handy-dandy online LRM page for [language-defined attributes](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-K.html) (keep this bookmarked while working with generics), looking for ones that work with "discrete" or "scalar" objects/types, we see that this includes:

- 'first
- 'image
- 'last
- 'max
- 'min
- 'pred
- 'range
- 'succ
- 'val
- 'value
- (assorted `wide_` variants of 'image and 'value)
- The usual suspects available to all objects of any type (eg: 'size, 'input, etc.)